# Vuejs component doesn't always show fetched data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

The component is within a laravel view, for some reason the data in the select tag isn't shown..sometimes. As weird as it sounds, it sometimes displays the data and sometimes it won't...There aren't any errors in the console or view.
Heres the component code :

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center" v-if="!loaded">
        <br>
        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-2x fa-pulse"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" v-else>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" >
                <label for="subjects">{{ trans('strings.choseSubject') }}</label>
                <select name="subjects" id="subjects" class="form-control selectpicker filter-input"
                        data-live-search="true" data-style="filter-input" @change="addSubject">
                    <option value="">{{ trans('strings.choseSubject') }}</option>
                    <optgroup v-for="category in subjects" :label="category.name" :data-catID="category.id">
                        <option :value="subject.id" v-for="subject in category.subjects">{{ subject.name }}</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="other-subject-form d-none">
                    <label for="otherSubject">{{ trans('strings.choseSubject') }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" id="otherSubject" name="otherSubject">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>
                <hr>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn-group mb-2" v-for="subject in user_subjects">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" :data-subjectID="subject.id" @click="deleteSubject" style="font-weight: bold">X</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" disabled style="opacity: 1 !important;">{{ subject.name }}</button>
                    &nbsp;
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The component functions:

```
  <script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            loaded: false,
            subjects: [],
            user_subjects: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSubjects: function () {
            axios.get('/t/get/subjects').then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                response.data.categories.map((value) => {
                    const category = {
                        id: value.id,
                        name: value.name,
                        subjects: value.subjects
                    };
                this.subjects.push(category);
                });
            }.bind(this));
            this.loaded = true;
        },
        getUserSubjects: function () {
            axios.get('/t/get/teacher/subjects').then(function (response) {
                this.user_subjects = [];
                response.data.subjects.map((value) => {
                    const subject = {
                        id: value.id,
                        real_id: value.subject.id,
                        name: value.subject.name
                    };
                $('#subjects').find('option[value="'+value.subject.id+'"]').remove();
                this.user_subjects.push(subject);
                });
                $("#subjects").selectpicker("refresh");
            }.bind(this));
            this.loaded = true;
        },
        addSubject: function (e) {
            var id = e.target.value;
            if(this.user_subjects.length<10)
            {
            axios.post('/t/subject/add', {
                subject_id: id,
            }).then(function (response) {
                this.getUserSubjects();
            }.bind(this));
        }
        else
        alert("You reached your maximum subjects! You can delete the subjects you don't need by pressing on the X button beside each subject");
        },
        deleteSubject: function (e) {
            var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-subjectID');

            axios.post('/t/subject/delete', {
                subject_id: id,
            }).then(function (response) {
                // var alasql = require('alasql');
                // this.user_subjects = alasql('DELETE FROM ? WHERE `id` = '+ id , [this.user_subjects]);
                this.user_subjects = this.user_subjects.filter(function (obj){
                    return obj.id != id
                });


                $('#subjects optgroup[data-catID="'+response.data.category_id+'"]').append($('<option>', {value:response.data.id, text: $('html').attr('lang') === 'ar' ? response.data.name_ar : response.data.name}));
                $("#subjects").selectpicker("refresh");
            }.bind(this));
        }
    },
    computed: {},
    created() {
        Vue.prototype.trans = string => _.get(window.i18n, string);
        console.log(this.subject);
        this.getSubjects();
        this.getUserSubjects();
        if(this.subjects == null){
            this.$forceUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

and in the blade view, its like this :

```
<br>
                    <subjects-selector></subjects-selector>
                    <br> <br>
```

Any idea why is this happening? It renders the result but its like a 50/50 chance....

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, it was caused by duplicate (or absent) keys on the `v-for` elements. You might fix the code by simply adding `:key` attribute:

```
<optgroup v-for="category in subjects" :key="category.id" :label="category.name" :data-catID="category.id">
    <option :value="subject.id" v-for="subject in category.subjects" :key="subject.id">{{ subject.name }}</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this still didn't solve it. I even added  v-bind:key.. didnt work ;(

Comment: i just realized, i think it may have to do with the created() function. it should be mounted() instead. the components may not even exist yet when you get a response from the ajax call, but in mounted() they would.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work either :(. I'm really not sure where to look or what to do since there are 0 js errors or in the API's. I do get the data but it just doesn't always render it.